# Edit a record saves a new record with updated fields

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, mvc

I'm writing a small Joomla component for my school but there is a little problem with it.

When I go to edit a record and then save it, instead of updating that record, it saves it as a new record with updated field.

I have checked the button in view for any mistakes, but can't see any issues.

Can any one please tell me some common mistakes that could cause this issue?

**Controller**

```
class StudentControllerStudent extends JControllerForm
{
    public function __construct($config = array()) {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class StudentModelStudent extends JModelAdmin
{
    public function getTable($type = 'Student', $prefix = 'StudentTable', $config = array())
    {
        return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
    }

        public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true) {
            $form = $this->loadForm('com_student.student', 'student',array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));

            if (empty($form))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return $form;
        }

        protected function loadFormData() {
            return $this->getItem();
        }

}
```

**view.html.php**

```
class StudentViewStudent extends JViewLegacy {

    protected $state;
    protected $item;
    protected $form;

    /**
     * Display the view
     */
    public function display($tpl = null) {
        $this->state = $this->get('State');
        $this->item = $this->get('Item');
        $this->form = $this->get('Form');

        // Check for errors.
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) {
            throw new Exception(implode("\n", $errors));
        }

        $this->addToolbar();
        parent::display($tpl);
    }


    protected function addToolbar() {
            JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('hidemainmenu', true);
            JToolbarHelper::title('edit item');
            JToolbarHelper::save('student.save');
            if (empty($this->item->id))
            {
                JToolbarHelper::cancel('student.cancel');
            }
            else
            {
                JToolbarHelper::cancel('student.cancel', 'JTOOLBAR_CLOSE');
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code else it's a little hard to track down the issue

Comment: ok sir i included my source. help me

Comment: Ok when when you're on the edit page for a student, in the URL, do you see something like `&layout=edit`?

Comment: I believe the issue is not in your view file, but in model. Do you check for user id before saving data?

Comment: Check `adminstartor/com_user/views/user/view.html.php` and `administrator/com_user/models/user.php` for better reference.

Comment: yes sir i see index.php?option=com_student&view=student&layout=edit.

sir i also use component-creator.com (which help users to create component) help and create the same student component but problem remain same i can email you  com_student that i created using component-creator.com. i just want to know where the mistake is. where i'm going wrong

Comment: To be honest I'm probably not the best person to be looking through component code as I'm still learning about them myself. I'm a module person.

Comment: that's OK.  @Lodder but any one can you please help me to debug out whats the problem i can share or mail student component to you..?

Comment: Could you please also share your administrator/components/com_student/views/student/tmpl/edit.php file? This doc could be useful https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component.

Answer (score 1):

Try this **function loadFormData()** for your model:

```
protected function loadFormData()
{
    $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_student.edit.student.data', array());

    if (empty($data))
    {
        $data = $this->getItem();
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following:

1) You must create JTable class and add following code in it:

```
function __construct(&$db)
{
     parent::__construct('#__yourtablename', 'id', $db);
     // Assumes "id" should be primary key of your table.
}
```

2) Check in DB and make sure that you have primary key set for "#__yourtablename". Also it must be set as AUTO_INCREMENT if not then try following queries in your MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `#__yourtablename` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`id`);
ALTER TABLE `#__yourtablename` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Again above assumes that, you have `id` column in your table.

Note: Replace "#__" with your table prefix.

Answer (score 1):

In the **view** of your component.
**components**->**com_mycom**->**view**->**tmpl**->**default.php** (*or* edit.php, some.php) depending on your needs.

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=com_student&view=student&layout=ifnotdefault&id='.$this->item->id ); ?>" method="post" class="form-validate" id="adminForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('id'); ?> // !important
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('somefield'); ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="student.save" /> // !important
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        <?php echo JHtml::_( 'form.token' ); ?>

</form>
```

Check 'form action',
Check 'field id',
Check 'task'

Comment: Please explain where this snippet should be written.  How should this technique be integrated with the OP's posted code? Please be generous with your knowledge and aim educate/empower thousands of people with your answer.